# Laravel : How to add days to datetime field?

Tags: php, laravel

How to add days to datetime field in Laravel?

For example,
there is a `updated_at` field in `articles` table:

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$updated_at=$article->updated_at;
```

I want to add 30 days to `updated_at` field.

In `Carbon`, it could be done like this:

```
$expired_at=Carbon::now()->addDays(30);
```

But how to do it in above example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since `updated_at` and `created_at` fields are automatically cast to an instance of `Carbon` you can just do:

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$article->updated_at->addDays(30);
// $article->save(); If you want to save it
```

Or if you want it in a separate variable:

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$updated_at = $article->updated_at;
$updated_at->addDays(30); // updated_at now has 30 days added to it
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Keep in mind you don't need to `use Carbon\Carbon` in this case, just apply `addDays()`

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Carbon::parse`

```
$article = Article::find(1);

$updated_at=Carbon::parse( $article->updated_at)->addDays(30);
```

Suppose if `updated_at` is `2017-09-30 22:43:47` then output will be `2017-10-30 22:43:47.000000`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried like this with raw php? If you want you can change your datetime format inside first parameter of `date()`

```
$updated_at=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+30 day', $article->updated_at));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without Carbon**

*For full example go to - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php*

The below code is for only add days

> $d->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```