# How to add Datatime + 2 years on

Tags: laravel, datetime, datetime-format, php-carbon

How to add a future date?

For example if we input the date `22/11/2019`, then in the other input column it will automatically be inputted on `22/11/2021` (2 years after the input date).

Can you give a reference and example?

In my search, Laravel uses carbon, but I don't know how to start because of lack of references

I search and found this thread [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504774/laravel-how-to-add-days-to-datetime-field) , but i still didnt know how to use carbon

Comment: `$t2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','22/11/2019')->addYear(2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example u getting input like format  `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
$input = "22/11/2019";

Carbon\Carbon::parse(date_format($input,'Y-m-d'))->addYears(2)
```

for second way create new carbon instance

```
$carbon = new Carbon\Carbon(2019,11,22);
$carbon->addYears(2)
```

for third way

```
 $format = 'd/m/Y';
 $inputDate = "22/11/2019";
 Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat($format,$inputDate)->addYears(2)->toDateString()
```

for more about carbon read this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon)

Answer (score 0):

With Carbon, you can add year like this.

```
// for your specified date
$dateInput = '22/11/2019';

$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateInput)->toDateString();

// date +2 Years
$nextDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateInput)->addYears(2);
```

Here you can find all methods available with carbon. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

Comment: @Adhik let me know if it helps.